# How can I select a window that is open in the background

Tags: pyautogui, pywinauto

I am trying to select a window that is open in the background and I have no idea what to do.

So far I have tried two methods:

First, I tried using PYAutoGUI to find the Taskbar Image then left click on the image in the taskbar (I assumed this didn't work because it was an image in the taskbar, but that assumption is completely unfounded (On a semi-related note, if you know where taskbar images are saved, please let me know about that as well)].

Second, I have tried to use pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle(), which has given me a list with two elements that I have absolutely no idea how to use. I've tried the .active() method, but I may be misunderstanding how that works.

As a side note, I have also looked into pywinauto, but I just didn't have the knowledge necessary to understand the "Getting Started" page.

If it isn't obvious, I'm pretty inept with coding. I could probably figure something out if I had 4 or 5 hours, but I figured it'd be easier to ask for help. (I can't post any code for this because I have none. I have literally no idea what to do).

Comment: you need to post some code for us to answer

Answer (score 0):

Found this, check it out:

```
import win32gui
import time

def windowEnumerationHandler(hwnd, top_windows):
    top_windows.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    results = []
    top_windows = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(windowEnumerationHandler, top_windows)
    for i in top_windows:
        if "windows title" in i[1]:
            win32gui.ShowWindow(i[0],5)
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(i[0])
            time.sleep(0.01)
            pass
```

Here is the full [explanation](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/10/20/pywin32-how-to-bring-a-window-to-front/)